# Trying to make video controls ontop of video

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

Im working on an assignment were we have to create a site with three videos using HTML5. 
This is what I have for now: http://jumpshare.com/v/hVQnbW?b=47ZPmk

I am familiar with how to create the play/pause and other functions of the video player. However I don't know what the best method is to have the controls be on the video.

I'd like to create something that works like most players; where controls show up on hover, there's a button in the middle to start the video when it's off.

My initial thought would be that i'd have to  create a div tag within the video tag (so borders don't go outside the parent (). From there have a CSS rule:

```
#video div{
       opacity: 0;
}

#video div:hover {
       opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Yea that doesn't make sense. It just makes the navigation opaque if i hover it but I want it if i hover the video :/

This is just a guess and my initial intuition but honestly I don't know the proper way to accomplish this.

Comment: you could either make the controls div the same size as the player - so hovering anywhere would change the opacity - or track the mouseover event (jQuery) on the video element to programmatically trigger the visibility of the controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a wrapping element that will wrap both the video element and the controls.

```
<div id="vid-container">
    <video src="video.mp4"></video>
    <div id="controls">... control stuff goes here ...</div>
</div>

<style>
    #vid-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px; // Make this the width of the video
    }

    // Place the controls to be at the bottom of the video, and on top, and invisible
    #controls {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    // Make the controls show when the video container is hovered
    #vid-container:hover #controls {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What if the contain is flexible. How would I make the controls adjust as the video size adjusts. For example, my site's video will become small as the window shrinks. But the current rules keep controls the same size.

Comment: You can make use JavaScript to keep it in shape. When I'm on my desktop I'll update the answer to give a short JavaScript snippet that can help you accomplish that.

Comment: Conversely, you can set the video width to 100% and adjust the width of the container when the window resizes. The video will always take the width of the container, while the container will take the height of the video

Comment: I think I have all the controls figured out in terms of flex. EXCEPT the PROGRESS bar. The size is set in Javascript and I don't know how to adjust it using javascript.

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/J7gFU/

Other than what I mentioned above. Im still having some problems with Replay (selecting play after the video is finsihed) and Seeking within the video. I am almost 100% sure both these issues revolve around the currentTime attribute which I can't get to work at all.

Answer (score 4):

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/5eAXs/).

Something like this should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<div class="video">
    <video width="640" height="360">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <div class="controls">
        <span class="pause">pause</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video {
    position: relative;
}
.controls {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .7;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .9em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: .9em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    z-index: 3;
}
.controls span {
    background: #222;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $video = $(".video"),
    $controls = $video.find(".controls");

$video.hover(
    function () {
        $controls.fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $controls.fadeOut();
    }
);
```